# Include dependencies in Angular CLI libararies

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I'm having issues with including Angular material dependency in the custom library. The primary application that includes a reference to the custom library throws an error "Cannot find @angular/material/core" and "@angular/material/tabs" while building the application. But these dependencies are present in the node_modules of the library.

I read online that adding the following to the library's package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3"
  }
```

should solve this issue, but it didn't seem to work.

After listing the dependencies, I did npm install to install the above listed packages. When I do an ng serve in the primary application, it does not include @angular/material and @angular/cdk in the node_modules of the primary application. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgIqY.png)

I would like my library to be self-contained and include angular/material when it is installed. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use those libraries in your primary application without explicitly depending on them. Even though they are getting installed via your custom dependency, node will not recognize those in your primary application. You need to also add them to your `package.json` in your primary application.

Comment: You're right. It is not getting installed in my primary application. But isn't there a way to make libraries self-contained?

Comment: What do you mean? You could of course expose whatever dependencies you want through your own dependency, but that seems like a very odd solution. Why do you want to do this exactly?

Comment: I want my library to be self-contained so that when users grab my library, they don't have to install the dependencies manually. Angular material is something my library is using for styling and I don't want users to install them manually. I tried including @angular/material in my dependencies within package.json, but that doesn't install the dependencies in my primary application

Comment: Whatever dependencies your library is using, will automatically get installed when your library is added to any project. All your library's dependencies will all be installed and ready to go, for your library only. Meaning they are installed, but only available to that library, and not to the project itself.

Comment: I give the path to my library in my primary application. And when I do an npm install <library-path> --save, it doesn't throw an error for @angular/material dependency. But when I build my library again, and do an ng-serve in my primary application, it says that it cannot find the @angular/material dependency. I again have to do an npm install <library-path> to get rid of it's dependency errors. Is this expected? Is there a way to avoid installing the library in primary application after building the library?

Comment: This  is the error I get when do an ng serve in the primary/mainapplication after installing the library and building the library again.                          
ERROR in ./node_modules/objy-monitor/fesm2015/library-sample.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core' in 'C:\Users\shikha\MainApplication\node_modules\library-sample\fesm2015'
ERROR in ./node_modules/library-sample/fesm2015/library-sample.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/tabs' in 'C:\Users\shikha\MainApplication\node_modules\library-sample\fesm2015'

Comment: Yes that is expected, you *need* to add `@angular/material` in your primary application for it to work. What your dependencies has does not matter.